# Error Flask command 'click' is not defined

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm creating a simple Flask application, this is my folder structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── flaskr
│   │   ├── db.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── usio.sql
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── historical.html
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── test_usio.py
│   ├── usio.db
│   ├── usio.json
│   ├── usio.py
│   ├── usio.sql
│   └── wsgi.py
├── logs
│   └── nginx
│       ├── access.log
│       └── error.log
├── usio.db
├── usio.json
└── usio.sql
```

On my `db.py` file I have the following code:

```
def init_db():
    db = get_db()

    with current_app.open_resource('usio.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    """Clear the existing data and create new tables."""
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

I'm following this tutorial [db creation tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/database/)

My flask version is 1.0.2

However when I try this command, from `flaskr` folder it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 894, in main
cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 557, in main
return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1061, in invoke
cmd_name, cmd, args = self.resolve_command(ctx, args)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1100, in resolve_command
cmd = self.get_command(ctx, cmd_name)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 515, in get_command
rv = info.load_app().cli.get_command(ctx, name)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 372, in load_app
app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/usio_flask/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
__import__(module_name)
 File "/home/kristian/usio/usio/app/flaskr/db.py", line 7, in <module>
@click.command('init-db')
NameError: name 'click' is not defined
```

This is my `__init__` file on `flaskr` folder:

```
def create_app():
    app = ...
    # existing code omitted

    from . import db
    db.init_app(app)

    return app
```

Also, I position myself on the `flaskr` folder before I try the `flask init-db` command, I also use this before running it `export=FLASK_APP=db`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `import click` from the tutorial.